# How to create a zooming effect in a slideshow presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, google-maps, slideshow, presentations

I would like to create a presentation, similar to Power Point slides, but with a Google Maps feature. When you zoom in in Google Maps, the content becomes more detailed. That's exactly what I need for my slides. The initial slide will show the system diagram I am trying to describe with it's major modules, when I click one of them I want that a zoom-in animation plays, then the detailed diagram of this module appears. It would be better if the same feature applied to sub-modules and be reversible.

There is any application that enables you to do such effect easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PREZI](http://prezi.com) might have the zoom-in effect that you are looking for--take a look at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0kriH9dKzk)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Try Windows Live Movie Maker

http://download.live.com/moviemaker?wa=wsignin1.0

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94lYVLPBXpg - introduction video

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these in my PPT below (MS Office 2003):

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0HwU0hzcrxVMmFkODRkNjktNzNlMC00N2JhLWFhNWUtNjcyMzVmMTE5ODNh&hl=pt_BR (download and open in MS Power Point; view animation detais)

Comment: Obrigado, mas a resposta escolhida atende melhor minha necessidade